# How to generate make dependencies from variable, for both .cpp and .h files?

Tags: c++, makefile

Here's my makefile as it exists currently

```
SRC=src
HDS=header
DRV=drivers
FILES=arraystack arraylist pointerstack pointerlist
FLAGS=-w -I $(HDS)

.PHONY: timing all $(FILES)
.DEFAULT_GOAL:=all

$(FILES): % :$(DRV)/%_driver.cpp $(HDS)/%.h $(SRC)/%.cpp
    g++ $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@ && ./$@ && rm $@

timing:
    g++ $(FLAGS) $^ -i $@ && ./$@ && rm $@

all: $(FILES) timing
```

the target timing needs to depend on arraystack.cpp, arraystack.h, arraylist.cpp, arraylist.h, pointerstack.cpp, pointerstack.h, pointerlist.cpp, and pointerlist.h. Additionally, these files are located in separate directories - .h files are in header/, .cpp files are in src/. Is there a way for make to automatically have those requirements based on some sort of pattern matching, from the existing list I have in my variables that has the root file names? It seems like a more elegant solution than a list of 8 .h and .cpp files should be available.

Comment: While your dependency problem is well stated, what you are trying to achieve with this Makefile is not really clear : why are you trying to execute (`... && ./$@ && ...`) your recipe products ?

See my answer below related to the dependency graph, and edit your question / create a new one accordingly if you have additional needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some [text manipulation functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), you can first construct a list of header and source files based on your directories and the `FILES` list :

```
HDS_FILES = $(addsuffix .h,$(addprefix $(HDS)/,$(FILES)))
SRC_FILES = $(addsuffix .cpp,$(addprefix $(SRC)/,$(FILES)))
DRV_FILES = $(addsuffix _driver.cpp,$(addprefix $(DRV)/,$(FILES)))
```

Then, add targets without recipes to specify the dependency between source, drivers and header files :

```
$(SRC)/%.cpp: $(HDS)/%.h
$(SRC)/%_driver.cpp: $(HDS)/%.h
```

Add translation targets to compile source and driver files to object files :

```
%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@

%_driver.o: $(DRV)/%_driver.cpp
    g++ -c $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Construct a list of all object files and create the final rule for your `timing` executable :

```
OBJS = $(addsuffix .o,$(FILES)) $(addsuffix _driver.o,$(FILES))

timing: $(OBJS)
    g++ $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

**Tip 1**: when tuning your Makefile, use the `$(info ...)` function to inspect the content of your variables without affecting your dependency graph, it helps to spot errors in the text transformation stuff.

```
$(info HDS_FILES = $(HDS_FILES))
$(info SRC_FILES = $(SRC_FILES))
$(info DRV_FILES = $(DRV_FILES))
$(info OBJS = $(OBJS))
```

**Tip 2**: you can specify multiple actions on separate lines in a recipe instead of using the shell built-in `&&` :

```
<some target>:
    g++ $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@ && ./$@ && rm $@

# Is (almost) equivalent to and clearer than
<some target>:
    g++ $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
    ./$@
    rm $@
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I needed, though slightly over-engineered for my use. I was able to solve it on my own with

    `timing: $(FILES:%=$(SRC)/%.cpp) $(FILES:%=$(HDS)/%.h) $(DRV)/timing.cpp`

And thanks for the tip about multilines, for some reason I was under the impression make only allowed single lines. Dunno where I got that from.